# How is the bomb ability of an alchemist affected when he takes levels in wizard (arcane bomber)?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, multi-classing

I'm currently trying to create a character that uses alchemist's bombs as his main source of damage, can use the Explosive Missile discovery and has a strong Will save.

After a lot of research, I only found one possible way to get a good Will save and the bomb class feature : the [arcane bomber](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/archetypes/paizo---wizard-archetypes/arcane-bomber) wizard archetype. The wording on its bomb ability is a bit confusing :

> Bomb (Su)
>
> At 1st level, the arcane bomber gains an ability nearly identical to
>   the alchemist’s bomb ability. Unlike the alchemist, at 1st level, the
>   arcane bomber chooses one type of energy from the following list:
>   acid, cold, fire, and electricity. He can throw bombs of that type,
>   but cannot modify them with discoveries. **This ability stacks with the
>   alchemist bomb ability to determine the level of bomb damage, but an
>   arcane bomber that becomes an alchemist does not gain that class’s
>   bomb ability, nor does an alchemist that becomes an arcane bomber gain
>   this bomb ability.**
>
> This ability replaces arcane bond.

If I first take levels in alchemist then levels in arcane bomber, does my bomb damage keep progressing ? What about my daily allotment of bombs ?

Answer (score 1):

An [alchemist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist) that later takes levels in [arcane bomber](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/archetypes/paizo---wizard-archetypes/arcane-bomber) [wizard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard) adds his alchemist level to his wizard level to determine how much damage his alchemist [bombs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist#TOC-Bomb-Su-) deal. Unless modified by another arcane bomber wizard class feature (e.g. spellblast bomb), the alchemist/arcane bomber uses *only* his alchemist level for his bomb's other effects (e.g. number of bombs per day). (A 2013 [thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2q0pz?Arcane-Bomber-Alchemist-How-does-this-work) makes a similar reading.)

Yes, the arcane bomber archetype's supernatural ability bomb could've used another run through editorial. Saying *[A]n arcane bomber that becomes an alchemist does not gain that class’s bomb ability, nor does an alchemist that becomes an arcane bomber gain this bomb ability* is misleading because, right before, the special ability explains what happens if a creature has both abilities, turning an attempt to clarify into confusion.